# Compile-time error: rendering a partial view within a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I am trying to render a partial page inside a partial page.
So i have in my layout page a call to my partial CreateMenu and here i pass the model from the layout page. This works perfect.
Now inside the CreateMenu partial i am trying to call MenuItem with the same syntax but then it fails. Visual studio shows the path as red (i know to 100% that it exists).

How can i render a partial from inside a partial.

MenuPartial's call to the render:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Models/Default/UserControls/_MenuItem.cshtml", Model.Modules[i])
```

Model.Modules[i] consists of MvcModule objects.

MenuItem:

```
@model Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule
<li class="@{if (Model.CanExpand) {<text>fullwidth</text>} else {<text>nodrop</text>}} first_fullwidth">
...
```

This results in a compilation error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0115:
>   "ASP._Page_Models_Default_UserControls__MenuItem_cshtml.Execute()":
>   Es wurde keine passende Methode zum
>   Überschreiben gefunden.
>            Line 46:         public override void Execute() {

Sorry for the German text. I have tried to get it to output English instead but VS 2010 refuses to change the settings =/

Comment: Any chance of translating that German to English, and supplying the code for the Execute method the error is referring to?

Comment: Its the mvc framework that is producing that code. It tries to execute the partial view and it fails. The error says: No suitable method found to override.

Comment: In visual studio 2010 i get "Cannot resolve partial view: 'path'". I know that it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a nested partial issue. You should be able to nest partials without any problem. It looks like the partial you're trying to render is in the `~/Models/Default/UserControls` directory. This isn't a place the default view engine looks for views. Try copying the `web.config` file from your `Views` directory into the `Models` directory.

If it were me, I would try to avoid storing views outside of the Views directory if at all possible to avoid weird issues like this.

Comment: So easy. The MainMenu got created there for some reason and that had always worked. Moved them to the views folder and *poff* it worked. Thanks!